# Закрытие приложения с помощью OnBackPressed в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Как сделать чтобы перейдя в `Fragment` при нажатии `OnBackPressed` приложение полностью закрывалось?
Написал вот такой код, но он не работает.

```
public class FragmentRink extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rink, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        requireActivity().moveTaskToBack(true);
        requireActivity().finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в метод onCreate() вроде должно работать.

```
OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(homeIntent);
        }
    };

    requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну можно кувалдой заколотить:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   super.onBackPressed();
   android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

Comment: Вообще не силен в андроид — но разве можно _убивать_ процесс ради закрытия?

Comment: Конечно это нехорошо - я же написал *кувалдой*